# View - Return 0 if no rows found in a grouped by query

Tags: mysql, view

Let's say I have the following MySQL view:

```
create or replace view total_transactions(account_id, total) as
select
  t.account_id,
  ifnull(sum(t.value), 0) as total
from transactions t
where t.paid IS TRUE
group by t.bank_account_id;
```

Let's say the account doesn't have any transaction yet, I want the view to return 0.
Right now, if I do a select like:

```
select * from total_transactions where account_id = 2060;
```

And account 2060 didn't had any transaction, it will return me nothing, instead of 0.

How could I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

---

## EDIT

I think it could be something with the `group by`...

If I execute the query that I'm using for the view without the group by, it works (return 0 even with no results), but if I use `group by` it comes null:

```
select
  t.account_id,
  ifnull(sum(t.value), 0) as total
from transactions t
where t.paid IS TRUE
and account_id = 2060;
```

Returns `0`, and

```
create or replace view total_transactions(account_id, total) as
select
  t.account_id,
  ifnull(sum(t.value), 0) as total
from transactions t
where t.paid IS TRUE
and account_id = 2060
group by t.bank_account_id;
```

Return an empty set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is not an entry in the view results, then this will always return `NULL` - That's SQL. If you change your `SELECT` that you use against the view, you can achieve what you want:

```
SELECT IFNULL(total, 0) FROM total_transactions WHERE account_id = 2060
```

**Edit:**

```
(SELECT IFNULL(total, 0) total FROM total_transactions WHERE account_id = 2060)
UNION
(SELECT 0 total)
```

Comment: that's weird: `Empty set (0,01 sec)`

Comment: @caarlos0 - See my edit. This should work when you get results and when you don't. But it's not the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

For positive values I use

```
select max(x.cnt) as cnt
from (
select ifnull(meta_value, 0) as cnt from wp_postmeta where post_id = 5543 and meta_key = '_bbp_voice_count'
union
select 0 as cnt) x
```

or for any

```
select x.cnt 
from (
select ifnull(meta_value, 0) as cnt from wp_postmeta where post_id = 5543 and meta_key = '_bbp_voice_count'
union
select 0 as cnt
) x
limit 1
```

Answer (score -1):

In production, don't use `SELECT *`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select) for a thorough response as to why.

So, assuming you're not, you can use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), which will return the first non-null value.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(total, 0) 
FROM
    total_transactions
WHERE
    account_id = '2600'
```

Comment: I already tried it: `select COALESCE(total, 0) as val from total_transactions where account_id = 2060;
Empty set (0,01 sec)`

Comment: Is `total` a field name in the `total_transactions` table or is it an alias for a calculated result?

Comment: This will not work because there are no rows, so there is nothing to coalesce.